# Deploy MVC 2 app in IIS7 404 error

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I am trying to publish an MVC 2 application to my local Win 7 IIS 7.

The app pool is Integrated 2.0, not classic.

The app is .net 3.5.

The project was originally started in VS2008, but I have upgraded to 2010.

I publish the app through the VS wizard to a file location, I have also tried publishing again in VS, but web deploy to localhost - neither makes a difference.

The app spins up fine when I just hit F5 in VS and work in debug mode.

Any ideas? I have googled about, but nothing has sorted it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the AppPool is set to allow 32bit apps?

Comment: It's a 32bit win 7 machine. Should be the only way no?